# Livereload UI "Add folder" doesn't work

Tags: directory, livereload

After attaching big size folder (Desktop folder) as a project folder "Add folder" stopped working. Reinstalling didn't help. How can I solve **this** or what is the **name of the file** I should put project directiories in so there will be no need to use UI "Add folder". I am using Win 7 Ultimate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The path to the file:** C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\LiveReload\projects.json

***projects.json* sample:**

`{
   "projects" : [
      {
         "customName" : "firstWebsite",
         "disableLiveRefresh" : false,
         "enableRemoteServerWorkflow" : false,
         "rubyVersion" : "system",
         "compilationEnabled" : true,
         "numberOfPathComponentsToUseAsName" : 1,
         "path" : "D:\\Websites\\Website1"
      }
   ]
}`